# Getting error while user does not select images how to resolve this

Tags: android, image, validation, kotlin, uri

I am getting an error while user does not select Images how to check image validation in kotlin

```
 fun getPath(uri: Uri): String? {

    var cursor = contentResolver.query(uri, null, null, null, null)

    if (cursor != null) {
        cursor!!.moveToFirst()
        var document_id = cursor.getString(0)
        document_id = document_id.substring(document_id.lastIndexOf(":") + 1)
        cursor.close()
        cursor = contentResolver.query(
            android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,
            null,
            MediaStore.Images.Media._ID + " = ? ",
            arrayOf(document_id),
            null
        )
    }


    cursor!!.moveToFirst()
        var path = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA))
        cursor.close()
        if (path == null) {
            path = ""
        }
        return path
}
```

here is on activity resultcode

```
 public override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)
    if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
        if (requestCode == SELECT_PICTURE) {
            val selectedImageUri = data!!.data
            selecteImageUri = Uri.parse(selectedImageUri.toString())
            if (selecteImageUri != null) {
                val filePath = getPath(selecteImageUri)
                binding.imageAddButton.text = filePath
            }

            else {
                AppLogger.toast("Please Select an Image")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I need to implement validation if user does not the select image from gallery and here is my intent function

```
  R.id.imageAddButton -> {
            val intent = Intent()
            intent.type = "image/*"
            intent.action = Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT
            startActivityForResult(
                Intent.createChooser(
                    intent,
                    "Select Picture"
                ), SELECT_PICTURE
            )
        }
```

I am always getting an error here

```
 cursor!!.moveToFirst()
```

how to resolve this please help me thank you in advance I would appreciate every answer

Comment: getting a crash when I do not select image

Comment: Add crash logs with question

Comment: com.example.moods.activity.Sign_up.getPath(Sign_up.kt:156)

Comment: Which image or what do you want to validate if the user does not select an image? Quite strange scenario which you might explain. You were asked to post the logs. Why dont you?

Answer (score 0):

```
public override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {
 super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)
 if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
    if (requestCode == SELECT_PICTURE) {
      if (data != null) {

        val selectedImageUri = data!!.data
        selecteImageUri = Uri.parse(selectedImageUri.toString())
        if (selecteImageUri != null) {
            val filePath = getPath(selecteImageUri)
            binding.imageAddButton.text = filePath
        }

        else {
            AppLogger.toast("Please Select an Image")
        }
      }
    }
 }
}
```